# Umbraco Razor query - how to implement "does not contain"?

Tags: razor, umbraco7

In Razor how would I write a query `where property does not contain` or `excludes`?

Basically looking for the opposite of:

```
Where(x => x.GetProperty<String>("myCategory").Contains(myString))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm. Unless I'm missing something:

```
Where(x => !x.GetProperty<String>("myCategory").Contains(myString))
```

:-)